# Cannot make POST request to webhook

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, discord

Im trying to make a POST request to the discord api, however it returns **{"message": "Cannot send an empty message", "code": 50006}**
I have also tried using FormData for the content posted, and a normal string.

```
function loadDoc()
{
    let json = JSON.stringify({
        "content": "test",
      });

    const http = new XMLHttpRequest()
    http.open("POST", "https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/MYWEBHOOK",true)
    http.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","multipart/form-data")
    http.send(json)
    http.onload = () => console.log(http.responseText)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe take a approach with fetch:

```
let url = 'YOUR_URL';
let content = {YOUR_DATA};

let optionalParam = {
    headers: {
    "content-type":"application/json; charset=UTF-8"
  },
  body: content,
  method: "POST"
};

fetch(URL, optionalParam)
.then(data => {return data.json()})
.then(res => {console.log(res)})
.catch(error => {console.log(error)})
```

Comment: Thanks so much, although your example did contain a syntax error. This is what worked for me `function loadDoc() {
  const url = 'https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/677059599391522827/MYWEBHOOK';
  const user = {
      content: 'test'
  };
  
  const options = {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(user),
      headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
  }
  
  fetch(url, options)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => console.log(res))
}`

Comment: Cool. Glad I was able to help!